# want to fetch data from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hello i want to display data from two tables
meaning
this table i need from it amount and created
and the user_id 
i want to get the username
from other table name is users
 [withdraw table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl9j9.png)
[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suqF1.png)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "aa";
$password = "aat&IpnFt";
$dbname = "aa";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$sql = " SELECT withdraw.amount, withdraw.account, withdraw.created
FROM withdraw
INNER JOIN users ON withdraw.user_id=users.username; ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["username"]. "   Name: " . $row["amount"]. "<br> " . $row["account"]. " " . $row["created"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing Found!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: need the solve please

Comment: You join the user ID on the username? They are most likely not the same.

Comment: what the solve as u see ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't select username of table2 and compare withdraw.user_id with users.username

Try:

```
$sql = " SELECT withdraw.amount, withdraw.account, withdraw.created, users.username
FROM withdraw
INNER JOIN users ON withdraw.user_id=users.id; ";
```

Comment: $sql = " SELECT withdraw.amount, withdraw.account, withdraw.created, users.username
FROM withdraw
INNER JOIN users ON withdraw.user_id=users.id; ";